# How does a TPM verify the identity of the calling process/service?

Tags: authentication, tpm, secret-sharing

Any application can use a TPM chip to securely create and store cryptographic keys.
For example for Digital Rights Management (DRM) or for prevention of cheating in online games.

However, how can a TPM be sure of the **identity of the process/service that is calling it** (and consequently be sure the secrets will not be shared with a malicious entity)?

"*Hi TPM, I'm Windows Defender, give me all the secrets you have*". (Actually just another malicious process).

I suppose there is some kind of authentication/authorization of the process/service in place.

Can someone explain how that works?